# File picker in xamarin forms application

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uri

I using a renderer to pick a file from the system to and showing it in the application. I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            intent.SetType("file/*");
            intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            String[] mimeTypes = { "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values" ,"application/pdf","image/*"};
            intent.SetType("*/*");
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraMimeTypes, mimeTypes);
            ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(intent, 7007);
```

And i got the data in OnActivityResult in MainActivity . Now that i have the Android.Net.Uri with me i want to find the absolute file path . here i used

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri contentUri)
        {
            String res = null;
            String[] proj = {Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data};
            ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {                
                int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                res = cursor.GetString(column_index);
            }
            cursor.Close();
            return res;
        }
```

I am testing in a Marshmallow device but i am getting null value as return every time. Any Guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can take a look to this plugin...](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)

There is a IOUtil.cs class

```
public class IOUtil
{

    public static string getPath (Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        bool isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri (context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument (uri)) {
                var docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId (uri);
                string [] split = docId.Split (':');
                var type = split [0];

                if ("primary".Equals (type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + split [1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument (uri)) {

                string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId (uri);
                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId (
                        Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("content://downloads/public_downloads"), long.Parse (id));

                return getDataColumn (context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument (uri)) {
                var docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId (uri);
                string [] split = docId.Split (':');
                var type = split [0];

                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".Equals (type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                } else if ("video".Equals (type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                } else if ("audio".Equals (type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                }

                var selection = "_id=?";
                var selectionArgs = new string [] {
                    split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn (context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".Equals (uri.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return getDataColumn (context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".Equals (uri.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return uri.Path;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static string getDataColumn (Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection,
    string [] selectionArgs)
    {

        ICursor cursor = null;
        var column = "_data";
        string [] projection = {
            column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query (uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
                int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow (column);
                return cursor.GetString (column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.Close ();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static bool isExternalStorageDocument (Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".Equals (uri.Authority);
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static bool isDownloadsDocument (Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".Equals (uri.Authority);
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static bool isMediaDocument (Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".Equals (uri.Authority);
    }

    public static byte [] readFile (string file)
    {
        try {
            return readFile (new File (file));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (ex);
            return new byte [0];
        }
    }

    public static byte [] readFile (File file)
    {
        // Open file
        var f = new RandomAccessFile (file, "r");

        try {
            // Get and check length
            long longlength = f.Length ();
            var length = (int)longlength;

            if (length != longlength)
                throw new IOException ("Filesize exceeds allowed size");
            // Read file and return data
            byte [] data = new byte [length];
            f.ReadFully (data);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (ex);
            return new byte [0];
        } finally {
            f.Close ();
        }
    }

    public static string GetMimeType (string url)
    {
        string type = null;
        var extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl (url);

        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension (extension);
        }

        return type;
    }
}
```

it works in this way

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Canceled) {
            // Notify user file picking was cancelled.
            OnFilePickCancelled ();
            Finish ();
        } else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (data.Data);
            try {
                var _uri = data.Data;

                var filePath = IOUtil.getPath (context, _uri);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (filePath))
                    filePath = _uri.Path;

                var file = IOUtil.readFile (filePath);

                var fileName = GetFileName (context, _uri);

                OnFilePicked (new FilePickerEventArgs (file, fileName, filePath));
            } catch (Exception readEx) {
                // Notify user file picking failed.
                OnFilePickCancelled ();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (readEx);
            } finally {
                Finish ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Android specific code in your Forms project, you can also use one of the FilePicker plugins that are available on NuGet. You can use this directly in your Forms project instead of jumping into an Android implementation.

The currently most actively maintained package is this one: https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows (note: I'm one of the contributors to the project).

Picking files is as easy as calling var result = await PickFile() and checking the result object. See also the sample code mentioned in the README.md of the Github project.